# When to hot encode ? Employee attrition level example

Tags: python, encoding, random-forest, one-hot-encoding

My question is the following :

**I have the following categorical variables in a dataset to predict employee's attrition.**
[image: categorical variables]

I have currently done one hot encoding of : **Job level, Job Role, Marital Status, Over18, Overtime**, and keeping the same label encoding for the ordinal columns (**PerformanceRating,Relationship Satisfaction and JobSatisfaction**).

I will then, after splitting into train and test set, use a Random Forrest Classifier to predict the Attrition (Yes/No).

Am I doing encoding the correct way (one hot for categorical and no encoding for the ordinal columns)?

Thank you so much for helping me with this doubt !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should doubt everything and take a performance test.

In general, decision tree models either don't need one-hot encoding or even perform worse after it. There's exceptions, for sure, but in modern ML world tree models if often respected for ability to work with high-dimension categorical data without much of pre-processing.

Comment: Yes I am aware that with decision-tree based models increasing the number of features leads to poorer performance, but my question is more : 

label encoding categorical variables can lead the tree to think there is a scale, an order(with 1 being less than 5) : in that extent, isn't is bad to perform label encoding instead of one hot encoding ? 
Best

Comment: I understand your question, but I mean it – depends on algo, but modern DT cope well with categorical variables, even if you don't encode it, thats it. Simply predictors that "think" of a scale, gives bad performance and/or being overweighted by other branches.